# Python: How to add rows with value the difference from the last two rows if the length (rows) of the data is less than a certain value

Tags: python, dataframe, append, diff

I have a python dataframe `df` with 2 columns 'timeline' and 'value' like below:

| timeline | value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | -1.2 |
| 1 | -1.0 |
| 2 | -0.8 |
| 3 | -0.7 |
| 4 | -0.63 |
| 5 | -0.56 |
| 6 | -0.48 |

I want to

1. Check if number of rows under `df` is less than 8 then append a row at the bottom with 'timeline' = 7 in this example and value is -0.40 ((-0.48) + ((-0.48) - (-0.56))), which is the last 'value' plus the difference of last 2 values.
2. If number of rows is 8 or more, we keep it and do nothing.

Desired Output `df1` with the last row appended.

| timeline | value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | -1.2 |
| 1 | -1.0 |
| 2 | -0.8 |
| 3 | -0.7 |
| 4 | -0.63 |
| 5 | -0.56 |
| 6 | -0.48 |
| 7 | -0.40 |

How can I do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
while len(df) < 8:
# Get difference from the last 2 records; 
   value_diff = df['value'].diff().iloc[-1]
# Append a new record;
   df_new_line = pd.DataFrame([[len(d1), (df['value'].iloc[-1] + value_diff)]], columns=['timeline','value'])
   df = pd.concat([df, df_new_line], ignore_index=True)

df
```